# download generated file from ios to mac

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a developer mac and the iOS project. I want to generate some helper files on iOS and insert it into main bundle. They generates slowly so I want to do it by myself, not by customers on their iPhones.

So how can I download file from application local folder to my Mac? And can I do this on simulator?

Comment: Yes, using NSFileManager you can achieve this. Go through tutorials for that to write files. I have done same like that, I was creating files on my mac desktop, using running my iOS app on simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get path to write file on iPhone Simulator with code like that:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];   
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Your_file_name.file"];
```

Then you can retrieve your file from `/Users/YOUR_NAME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1(VERSION_OF_SIMULATOR)/Applications`. Find you app in this directory and in `YOUR_APP/Documents` you'll find your file.

P.S. Library will be hidden directory, so don't forget to run those commands in terminal first:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

Comment: or dont change your Finder settings and copy via command  line

Comment: You can also use Command-Shift-G and type ~/Library into the window, and it will take you into the Library folder.  From there, you can navigate to the files normally.